# Selecting between multiple sql tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select, multiple-tables

I have two tables: one for a list of students, and one table to map the student's with some playground toys.

When I select a playground toy, I want to be able to see a list of
students with the following restrictions:

- A student can only have one type of toy at a time. (A student with basketball(s) can't show up in the list when I select soccer ball).
- A student with a specific toy can have multiple of different colors (A   student with a yellow basketball can also have the blue ball).

I'm looking to write an SQL query or convert the tables into a C# list which selects from the student's table such that it will return entries which follow the restrictions. I am using MVC framework in C#, and will be calling the query in the controller through a method which has already been written functionally.

```
Students
+------------+--------------+
| StudentId  | name         |
+------------+--------------+
|     1      | Bob          |
|     2      | Samuel       |
|     3      | Tim          |
| ...
+------------+--------------+

PlaygroundMap
+-----+-----------------+--------+------------+
| id  | name            | color  | studentid
+-----+-----------------+--------+------------+
| 1   | basket ball     | yellow | 1
| 2   | basket ball     | blue   | 1
| 3   | tennis ball     | black  | 2
| 4   | tennis ball     | red    | 2
| 5   | soccer ball     | purple | 3
| ...
+-----+-----------------+--------+------------+
```

I'm still new to SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A `SELECT` is not going to manage data constraints. You need to manage that when putting the data into the table.

Comment: "I need an SQL query", so you expect us to do it for you?

Comment: How about when it's out of the table and into a list? If I extract the two tables into a list, could I use some operator to remove students from the list based on their IDs in the PlaygroundMap table?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I'm expecting guidance, sorry if my phrasing sounds a little demanding.

Comment: @ALam, if a student does have more than one toy, how do you choose which to show and which one violates the restriction?

Comment: You really should add the constraints to the table(s) themselves, and you'll need to delete the rows that don't comply with the constraints.

Comment: Look up how to do a `JOIN` and try something.  Then get back to us if you get stuck.

Comment: @TomH I've tried pulling the two tables out, and using the studentIDs from the PlaygroundMap to remove entries from the full Student's list, but there were a couple errors. I also tried some basic SQL queries, but I couldn't understand how to cross-select (or what-not) from multiple tables.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath My question is a very simplified paraphrase of the actual project. The way it's set up, I'm unable to change anything with the actual tables.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not worrying about current error cases, rather just displaying the list such that it won't create any more violations.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make a composite primary key in playgroundmap table for that at database level between name and studentid in playgroundMap table

Answer (score 0):

How about using the below, I think it matches all of the requirements.

```
SELECT Students.name, PlaygroundMap.Name, PlaygroundMap.color
FROM Students 
    JOIN PlaygroundMap
        ON Students.StudentId = PlaygroundMap
WHERE Students.StudentID <> (
SELECT Students.StudentID
FROM Students
    JOIN PlaygroundMap
        ON Students.StudentId = PlaygroundMap
WHERE COUNT(PlaygroundMap.name)
GROUP BY PlaygroundMap.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from student
where StudentId NOT IN 
    (select distinct StudentId from PlaygroundMap) 
or StudentId IN
    (select distinct StudentId from PlaygroundMap where PlaygroundMapName = @playground)
```